# Kotlin generics: Cannot sort by type with star projected parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to sort a list of objects - lets call them `StockRow`s,  by their values, which all implement

`interface DetailedStockCell <in T: DetailedStockCell<T>> : Comparable<T>`

for example, this class represents a value in `StockRow`:

```
data class SharesCell(val shares: Int?) : DetailedStockCell<SharesCell> {
    override fun compareTo(other: SharesCell): Int {
        return this.shares.compareTo(other.shares)
    }
}
```

Now, this is `StockRow` - with all it's values. It also contains a `Map` to associate each value to an index.

```
data class StockRow(
                            val symbolCell: SymbolCell,
                            val sharesCell: SharesCell,
                            val priceCell: PriceCell,
                            val totalGainCell: TotalGainCell,
                            val percentOfPortfolioCell: PercentOfPortfolioCell
                            ) {
    
    val columnIndex : Map<Int, DetailedStockCell<*>> = mapOf(
        0 to symbolCell,
        1 to sharesCell,
        2 to priceCell,
        3 to totalGainCell,
        4 to percentOfPortfolioCell
                           )
```

But when I try to sort a List of `StockRows` by a selected values via `columnIndex` map,  `sortBy{}` fails to infer the sorted type

```
val masterList: List<StockRow> = //whatever list

fun sortStocksBy(selectedColumn: Int) : List<StockRow>{
    return masterList.sortedBy { stockRow -> stockRow.columnIndex[selectedColumn] }
}
```

Error:

```
Type parameter bound for R in inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortedBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): List<T>
 is not satisfied: inferred type DetailedStockCell<*> is not a subtype of Comparable<DetailedStockCell<*>>
```

It's the star projection argument that needs to be recursively fulfilled.

Now, I can get around this by not using Generics at all, and just using casting in each implementation of `DetailedStockCell`, But I'd like to get this working somehow with Generics.
From what I understand so far, is that there is a clash between `in` and `out` type bounds.
`Comparable` requires an `in` bound for it's type, but the map holding the values must have an `out Any` bound to be read successfully by `sortBy{}`. I mean - this *almost* works, except that now `T` in `Comparable<T>` is shouting it need to be `in`:

```
interface DetailedStockCell <out T> : Comparable<T>

data class DetailedStockRow(...){
    val columnIndex: Map<out Int, DetailedStockCell<Any>> = mapOf(...)
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, so any wise help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really combine sorting and generics like this. Sorting requires knowing the type to sort by so the method signature can be known at runtime, but this isn't possible with generics at runtime because of type erasure.

The existence of the `DetailedStockCell` doesn't really accomplish anything. `sortedBy` wants something that's comparable to its own type, but something being a `DetailedStockCell` doesn't guarantee that to the compiler. It could be comparable to some other class that implements it, but not to instances of the same class. I would just remove that interface and have each cell type implement `Comparable<itsOwnType>`.

So you need to specifically sort each type with its concrete type. You can drop the `columnIndex` map and make a function like this:

```
fun Iterable<StockRow>.sortedByColumn(columnIndex: Int): List<StockRow> {
    return when (columnIndex) {
        0 -> sortedBy(StockRow::symbolCell)
        1 -> sortedBy(StockRow::sharesCell)
        2 -> sortedBy(StockRow::priceCell)
        3 -> sortedBy(StockRow::totalGainCell)
        4 -> sortedBy(StockRow::percentOfPortfolioCell)
        else -> error("Nonexistant column: $columnIndex")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Tenfour04, your answer explains well why I was on the wrong track. It's also a good example of the limitations of Generics, which is sometimes hard to wrap your head around.